Escaping "$!" in bash
I am trying to escape special characters and it looks like I've caught most/nearly everything except a specific combination of $!.
If a file name has both $! neighboring, then this script no longer captures those characters and instead removes them.
I am struggling with fully understanding why and how to best adjust this script in order to preserve "$!"
#run the executable with the params.
eval_args=()
for arg in "${@}"; do
    # Parsers previously had single quotes ("'/path/to/rom'" ), this allows those shortcuts to continue working. 
    removeLegacySingleQuotes=$(echo "$arg" | sed "s/^'//; s/'$//")
    escaped_arg=$(printf "%q" "$removeLegacySingleQuotes")
    eval_args+=("$escaped_arg")
done

echo "eval ${exe} "${eval_args[*]}""
# If the ROM has an "!" (ex: WarioWare: Twisted!), use set +H to temporarily allow !'s
set +H
eval "${exe}" "${eval_args[@]}"
set -H

Example:
./mgba.sh "WarioWare, Inc. - Mega Microgame$!.gba"
eval /home/deck/Applications/mGBA.AppImage WarioWare\,\ Inc.\ -\ Mega\ Microgame.gba

The second line shows that it's not correctly preserving $!

Why are you using eval at all?

What are good alternatives to eval?

That depends on why you think you need eval here. Simply not using eval, as KamilCuk suggests in his answer, is probably all you need. You can't make up for someone incorrectly passing an argument to your script inside your script.

See Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead? and BashFAQ/048 (Eval command and security issues).

You are calling your script with:
./mgba.sh  "WarioWare, Inc. - Mega Microgame$!.gba"

Before your script executes, "$!" is replaced by the last background pid. If you want to preserve the literal value of a string, you have to escape it upon writing.
./mgba.sh "WarioWare, Inc. - Mega Microgame\$!.gba"

or
./mgba.sh 'WarioWare, Inc. - Mega Microgame$!.gba'

Your script is really simple - it should just pass properly quoted expansion of arguments and call the exe. Nothing to do in your script. Just:
"${exe}" "$@"

Check your scripts with shellcheck. Debug your scripts with set -x, also interactive shell.

This is a much simpler approach, thank you. Is there no way of escaping it in the script itself though, even with using the simpler "${exe}" "$@" ?

Before your script executes Means that before your script executes the replacement has been done already in the past. There is nothing to do in your script, your script never sees $!.

That makes sense, appreciate the help!

You can use single quotes '. Enclosing the string in them makes it immune to expansion and command substitution.
Single quotes:
export TestVar=test
echo '$TestVar'
# Output is $TestVar

Double quotes:
export TestVar=test
echo "$TestVar"
# Output is test

